# TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type NoneType). Not sure how to solve this

Tags: python, django

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[![Nurse admin page[![][1]][1][image: ][1][2]][[image: enter image description here][2]]**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
    
#Work Related aka Department and Work Shift

class Department(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class WorkShift(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    start_datetime = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    end_datetime = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

#Personel Related aka Employees and Patients

class Doctor(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    department = models.ForeignKey(Department, default="", null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Nurse(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    department = models.ForeignKey(Department, default="", null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    reports_to = models.OneToOneField(Doctor, default="", blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    work_shift = models.OneToOneField(WorkShift, default="", blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
         return str(name)

class Patient(models.Model):
    STATUS = (
        ('Sick', 'Sick'),
        ('Healing', 'Healing'),
        ('Cured', 'Cured'),
        ('Deceased', 'Deceased'),
    )

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True, choices=STATUS)
    department = models.ForeignKey(Department, default="", null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    care = models.ForeignKey(Nurse, default="", blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Doctor, Nurse, Patient
from django.http import HttpResponse

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    patient = Patient.objects.all()
    nurse = Nurse.objects.all()
    doctor = Doctor.objects.all()

    total_patient = patient.count()
    sick = patient.filter(status='Sick').count()
    healing = patient.filter(status='Healing').count()
    cured = patient.filter(status='Cured').count()

    total_nurse = nurse.count()

    # if request.method == 'POST':
    #     form = 

    context = {
        'patient':patient, 'nurse':nurse,
        'doctor':doctor, 'total_patient':total_patient,
        'sick':sick, 'healing':healing, 'cured':cured,
        'total_nurse':total_nurse
    }

    return render(request, 'lifesaver/index.html', context)

def patient(request):
    patient = Patient.objects.all()

    total_patient = patient.count()

    context = {
        'patient':patient,
        'total_patient':total_patient
    }
    return render(request, 'lifesaver/patient.html', context)][1]
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import Doctor, Nurse, Patient
from django.auth.contrib.forms import UserCreationForm

class DoctorForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(widget = forms.TextInput(attrs = 
    {

            'placeholder': 'Add a New Doctor',
            'class': 'form-control'
    }
    ))

    department = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=department.objects.all)

class NurseForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(widget = forms.TextInput(attrs = 
    {
            'placeholder': 'Add a New Nurse',
            'class': 'form-control'
    }
    ))

class PatientForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(widget = forms.TextInput(attrs = 
    {
        'placeholder': 'Add a New Patient'
        'class': 'form-control'

    
    }))
```

HTML for patient

```
{% extends 'lifesaver/main.html' %}

{% block content %}

<h1>SUPERSTAR</h1>

{% for patient in patient %}
    {{patient.name}}
{% endfor %}

{% endblock content %}
```

I get this error when I go to try to add another `Nurse`. The URL is http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/lifesaver/nurse/add/. Everything else behaves as expected, except the adding the Nurse part.

If I try to remove the `def __str___` part, the error still displays. I believe the error lies in the:

```
work_shift = models.OneToOneField(WorkShift, default="", 
                                             blank=True, 
                                             null=True, 
                                             on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

part since when I included that code, the error spawned. Furthermore, the code is to add a work shift to certain employees and the goal is that the employees shift will display in their profile.

How do I fix this issue?

EDIT: When accessing the HTML template, the web page behaves as expected and has no issues.

Comment: `return str(Nurse.name)` is definitely wrong. Look at `__str__()` in your other classes, these return `self.name`

Answer (score 1):

In your Nurse model replace this:

```
def __str__(self):
         return str(Nurse.name)
```

with this:

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention but that was the code you mentioned was the original code but the error still persists.

Comment: can you add the `form` you are using to the question and the `html` for it?

Comment: thanks for looking into this. I've added the form.py and the html for patient. I don't have a HTML for nurse as of yet

Comment: First off it should be `self.name` in your `__str__` method not `str(name)` Ill look into it

Comment: are you sure youre adding the valid `name` when you are creating your Nurse instance in admin?

Comment: Sorry I put a typo. I've did the following code: def __str__(self): return self.name under Nurse and I still get the error in that link

Comment: can you screenshot your admin Nurse creation form with the valid data?

Comment: sorry I thought I had added a screenshot when I made this post. Is this screenshot the screenshot you're looking for?

Comment: let that one stay but also add one before you click `Add new Nurse` button

Comment: I've added more screenshots and I hope they help. For the adding one, I removed the code work_shift = models.OneToOneField(WorkShift, default="", blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE), which worked

Comment: have you run migrations after adding the `WorkShift` ForeignKey and do you have any `WorkShift` instances?

Comment: yeap. I thought it was a migration issue and I've ran numerous migrations. I just checked the WorkShift admin page and I've noticed a value called "-" and there are no values inside. When I click on it, it leads me that yellow error page. Perhaps maybe thats where the error lies? I've also added screenshots

Comment: well then remove that object and the error should be fixed :)

Comment: I've attempted to remove it through the admin page but I get the same error. I've also attempted to delete the other valid object but get the same error. do you know how to remove the object? sorry I just started Django

Comment: Well the simple solution would be to delete your `sqlite3` database from your project root folder and then run migrations, then make sure you create objects with valid data if you are using `nullable` fields, looks like your issue is caused by having an object that has 0 data stored in it

Comment: I was able to fix it by changing the def __str__ in the workshift to def __str__(self): return self.name if self.name else ''. Deleted it there and then revert it back to def __str__(self): return self.name

Thank you so much for you help man. You're a legend mate

Comment: That is also a way to do it, have a good one my friend :)